# Should I insulate my pizza oven between the firebrick base and concrete?

Tags: insulation, heat

I am building a pizza oven for my garden. The 'table' will be standard red brick and concrete slabs to form the work top.

On top of the work top, I was intending to lay a layer of firebrick, and place the oven on top.

Research shows firebricks conduct heat and now I am worried if the fire bricks (the base of the oven) get hot, they will transfer into the concrete slabs (the work top).

My questions is, would fire cement insulate and as such protect the concrete worktops or would I need some insulation between the firebrick and concrete worktop?

Comment: There is an abundance of info (*tutorials, forums etc*,) on building wood fired pizza ovens on the internet. Forums allow a discussion and provide much info from others who have done it.

Comment: @AlaskaMan yes, you are right. But, 1) I trust stack exchange and 2 - I have researched if fire cement conducts or insulates and I find nothing to state it either way :(

Comment: https://community.fornobravo.com/ You want your slab to get hot and hold that heat, it is integral to the design/function of a 700 degree oven.

Comment: I guess it's off topic here @AlaskaMan?

Comment: Not off topic, just may be better asked on a forum where you can have a discussion. Someone here will likely have some good advice for you.

Comment: I definitely suggest you watch the how its made pizza oven segment - https://www.google.com/search?q=how+its+made+pizza+oven&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS939US939&oq=how+its+made+pizza+oven&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30.17018j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_hVx3YMOuJKWE9PwPm9mM-AM15

Comment: I have made the oven (with a gym ball). What they dont show is if they insulate between workstop and oven base (and if fire cement is sufficient)

Answer (score 1):

Fire brick and fire bed type refractory cement are different things both will get hot and disperse the heat. When I used to install a lot of wood stoves we poured the beds in every stove we installed, 30 years later the few stoves I have installed have used fire brick. I doubt that the oven will be hotter than coals from a wood stove and you have the additional layers below as a heat sink so for me based on what I have seen and the move to fire brick (easier install easy replace, partial replace when needed) I would go with the fire brick.
The last high efficiency stove I installed used 1” fire brick in the top to divert the air flow across pipes I did not think that would last but I did not replace them until they had been for 8-10 years so they held up with the coals and in the flame and heat of the exhaust. If really concerned create a small air gap under the brick to eliminate contact heat transfer, well significantly reduce it.